# Why can't I have two jQuery functions one inside the other?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create two select boxes, a `dad` select box and a `son` select box, when you select an option within `dad` with a value equals `1` for instance, the only options available on the `son` select box will be those with the value equals `1`. However, I'm using a function `.change` on `dad` and a `.each` through `son`, I'm relatively new to jQuery, so I don't know if what I'm doing is considered illegal.

Any help is appreciated.

```
$('#dad').change(function(d){
  $("#son > option").each(function(s) {
    if($(d).val() == $(s).val()){
       $(s).show(0);
    }else{
      $(s).hide(0);
    }
  });
});
```

**My full code**:

```js
var dadArray = [[1,'Option1'],[2,'Option2']];
var sonArray = [[1,1,'Son1'],[2,2,'Son2'],[3,2,'Son2']];

function getDad(dad,id){
  var size = dad.length;
  for(var i=0;i<size;i++){
    $(id).append('<option value="'+dad[i][0]+'">'+dad[i][1]+'</option>');
  }
}
function getSon(son,id){
  var size = son.length;
  for(var i=0;i<size;i++){
    $(id).append('<option id="son'+son[i][0]+'" value="'+son[i][1]+'">'+son[i][2]+'</option>');
  }
}

$('#dad').change(function(d){
  $("#son > option").each(function(s) {
    if($(d).val() == $(s).val()){
       $(s).show(0);
    }else{
      $(s).hide(0);
    }
  });
});

getDad(dadArray,'#dad');
getSon(sonArray,'#son');
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<title>iterateSelectBox</title>
</head>
<body>
  <select id="dad">
  </select>
  <select id="son">
  </select>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: My first guess would be `if(d.val() == s.val() ){` and `s.show()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two core problems, both related to the arguments passed to callback functions not being what you think:

```
 $('#dad').change(function(d){
     $(d).val(); 
 });
```

`d` is the jQuery-normalized change event object. The `#dad` select is available as `this` and `d.target`.

```
$("#son > option").each(function(s) {
     $(s).val();
});
```

Here `s` (first argument to `each` callback) is the index of current item in the list. You can change it to `.each(function(i, s) {...`, or use `this` inside the callback to refer to the option element.

In both cases jQuery isn't very helpful and doesn't produce an error like "hey you can't query an event object" or "integer is not a valid selector", because you can pass almost anything to the `$()` function and it'll try to make sense of it.

Fixed code here: http://jsfiddle.net/5n3ofr8n/

```
$('#dad').change(function(){
    var selected = this.value;
    $("#son > option").each(function() {
    if( selected == this.value){
        $(this).show();
    }else{
      $(this).hide();
    }
  });
});
```

Or you could just simplify the function to use the power of jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/5n3ofr8n/1/

```
$('#dad').change(function(){
    $('#son option').hide().filter('[value=' + this.value +']').show();
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for providing such an explanatory and useful answer +1

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution: http://jsfiddle.net/vo0udbt1/1/

```js
var dadArray = [[1,'Option1'],[2,'Option2']];
var sonArray = [[1,1,'Son1'],[2,2,'Son2'],[3,2,'Son3']];

function getDad(dads, id) {
    //append once to cut down on redraws.  also use map to do the loop for you
    $(id).append($.map(dads, function(dad){
        return '<option value="'+dad[0]+'">'+dad[1]+'</option>';
    }));
}

function getSon(sons,id) {
    //append once to cut down on redraws.  also use map to do the loop for you
    $(id).append($.map(sons, function(son){
        return '<option id="son'+son[0]+'" value="'+son[1]+'">'+son[2]+'</option>';
    }));
}

//passed in element here is the event, not the element
var $dad = $('#dad');
var $son = $('#son');
$dad.change(function(e){
    //hide all the options
    $son.find('> option').hide();
    //show sons with save value
    $son.find('> option').filter(function(){
        return (this.value == $dad.val());
    }).show();
    //change index incase selected son was hidden
    $son.prop('selectedIndex', 0);
});

getDad(dadArray,'#dad');
getSon(sonArray,'#son');
```

```html
<select id="dad"></select>
<select id="son"><option></option></select>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was writing this a while ago but had to take care of something for a while. Other answers already explained why this original code doesn't work. Below you can find an improved version, in terms of readability and performance

```js
var dadArray = [{
  value: 1,
  label: 'Option1'
}, {
  value: 2,
  label: 'Option2'
}];
var sonArray = [{
  value: 1,
  label: 'Son1'
}, {
  value: 2,
  label: 'Son2'
}, {
  value: 2,
  label: 'Son2'
}];

function createDad(id) {
  var size = dadArray.length;
  var $elm = $(id);
  for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    var dad = dadArray[i];
    $elm.append($('<option/>', {
      value: dad.value,
      text: dad.label
    }));
  }
}

function createSon(id) {
  var size = sonArray.length;
  var $elm = $(id);
  for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    var son = sonArray[i];
    $elm.append($('<option/>', {
      id: 'son' + i,
      value: son.value,
      text: son.label
    }));
  }
}


createDad('#dad');
createSon('#son');

$('#dad').change(function(event) {
  var $dad = $(this);
  $("#son > option").each(function(i,elm) {
    var $elm = $(elm);
    $elm[$dad.val() == $elm.val() ? 'show' : 'hide']();
  });
}).trigger("change");
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
  <title>iterateSelectBox</title>
</head>

<body>
  <select id="dad">
  </select>
  <select id="son">
  </select>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

When on `dad` change you need to show the options of the `son` with that value?

```
$('#dad').on('change',function(){
  var needle = $(this).val();
  $("#son option").each(function() {
   var option = $(this);
   option.hide();
   if(option.val() == needle) {
     option.show();
   }
  });
```

Additionaly you can pass data into html attributes, for example `<option value="some value" data-parent="Dad Number One">Son of the 1st dad</option>`. You can get that attribute(data-parent) using jquery, like so `$('option').attr('data-parent')` which will return `Dad Number One` in this example